# Perl - DBI - MySQL - Easy way to get row id after update?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Is there an easy way to get the id of the row that was affected by an update statement from DBI?  In this particular case, it will always be either 0 or 1 row.  I didn't want the expense of having to redo the selection part of the query again to get the data, as it is kind of costly.

I am have to do the update first, because otherwise I introduce the possibility of a race-time condition between the select and the update.

Comment: are you talking about INSERT sql sentences?

Comment: no inserts, only update followed by select

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233313/get-primarys-keys-affected-after-select-update-or-insert-only-using-sql for example

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL Server has a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: Oracle has also SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Comment: @MiguelPrz: And it looks like MySQL and PostgreSQL do too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database engine, you are likely to have a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` facility. You should use this to

- `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the record you want to update
- Save the `ID` from the record, and do the `UPDATE` using the `ID` instead of the original criteria

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this [related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034136/select-updated-rows-in-mysql/15034351#15034351) (I've linked to the answer by [@Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter)) -- this is the way I've always handled it.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) about SELECT ... FOR UPDATE may helps you, working with transactions.